# Get locations of user from a tweet search with twitteR and dplyr

Tags: r, twitter, dplyr

I would like to obtain the locations of user from a searchTwitter results using dplyr.

First, I search for tweets containing a specific tag and I convert them in the dplyr framework:

```
tw = searchTwitter('#twitter', n = 100, since = '2012-01-01') 
tw_df <- tbl_df(map_df(tw, as.data.frame))
```

Then I want to extract the user to get their locations. I am using the getUser() and the location() function:

e.g.

```
location(getUser('testusername'))
```

However, when I want to combine this in a dplyr pipeline, I got an error:

```
tw_df %>%
  mutate(user.location = location(getUser(screenName)))
```

error:

```
Error: error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'location': Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("users", "show", sep = "/"), params = params,  : 
  Not Found (HTTP 404).
```

I thought it could be a restriction of twitter multiple requests, however, outside of dplyr pipeline, it works:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    test.user <- getUser("testusername");
    print(location(test.user))
}
```

Is it possible to do this request using dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
library(twitteR)
library(dplyr)
tw <- searchTwitter('#twitter', n = 3) 
tw_df <- twListToDF(tw)
tw_df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(user.location = twitteR::location(getUser(screenName))) %>%
  select(user.location)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 1]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
# # A tibble: 3 x 1
#                   user.location
#                           <chr>
# 1                              
# 2 En la VI Republica, Venezuela
# 3                 San Mateo, CA
```

`tw_df %>% mutate(user.location = location(getUser(screenName)))` feeds `screenName` with all screen names at once. That does not work here.

Comment: I am getting randomly this error using your code:
Error: unable to find an inherited method for function 'location' for signature '"NULL"'
In addition: Warning message:
In twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("users", "show", sep = "/"), params = params,  :
  Rate limit encountered & retry limit reached - returning partial results.
Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: Seems you hit the rate limit. Use `lookupUsers` instead of `getUser`, drop `dplyr` and check out the ressources on handling the rate limiting.

Comment: That's strange as soon as I go over 5, I have the error... that's a pretty low resource limit.

Comment: If you "behave" and respect the twitter terms, you should be able to do 180 requests per 15-min window. But, as I said, [`users/show`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) / `getUser()` is not meant for bulk queries anyway.